# Организация указателей элементов двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, матрицы, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте. Допустим у меня динамически выделенный двумерный массив 3*5 (пусть будет матрица):

```
int** mat = malloc(sizeof(int*)*3);
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    mat[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

Я хочу пробежаться не по всей матрице, а только по всем элементам от начальной точки (1,2) (вверх и вправо соотвественно).

Верна ли подобная аритметика указателей в данном случае:

```
int** ptr = &(&mat[1][2]);
ptr[0][0] == mat[1][2]; /// верно ли равенство ?
ptr[0][1] == mat[1][3]; /// "
ptr[1][1] == mat[2][3]; /// "
```

**со сдвигом вправо** в целом проблем меньше, так как можно просто взять **original_mat + i** и тогда например **mat[0][5] = original_mat[0+i][5]** является верным использованием ариметики, **как на счет сдвига вверх**? То есть верно ли сказать что расстояние между адрессами 2 строки в ширь явяется расстоянием "одного передвижения" размером соответвующего указателя. Или это совсем не обязательно и они разбросаны.

**Или же разбросаны только в случае динамического выделения**, а например при стандарте с99 если определить матрицу **mat[length][width]**, то выше изложенный метод доступа с определенной точки к суб-матрице будет работать ?

**Или единственный способ это сделать**, это создать новый двумерный массив с соответсвующими размерами и переместить указатели всей строки (каждый указатель является указателем на сплошной ряд элементов всего столбца или части его - зависит от второй координаты) вручную в массив указатель друг за другом ?

Насколько понятна задача (**доступ к суб-матрице с определнной точки**), насколько понятны предложения о решение ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас Вы выделяете память сначала на указатели строк, затем каждому такому указателю выделяете место для самой строки. Верно, что выделенные куски памяти под строки не обязаны располагаться друг за другом.

Не могу подсказать, как работает выделение памяти сразу под двумерный массив, но точно могу сказать, что подобный способ не единственный. Советую использовать линейный массив как двумерный — в нём легко будет перепрыгивать по указателям.

```
int h = 3;
int w = 5;
int* mat = malloc(sizeof(int) * h * w);
```

Тогда обращаться к элементу с индексами (1,2) можно будет как **mat[1*w+2]**.

**UPD.** В целом, первые два Ваши равенства логически правильны. С третьим не согласен, думаю, при итерации первого индекса второй как бы переходит в ноль. То есть:

```
ptr[1][1] == mat[2][1];
```

Но стоит учесть нюанс, что адрес (`&`) мы можем брать у переменной в памяти. Брать указатель указателя не получится, ибо это не переменная, а значение. Не компилируется, в общем.

Дальше я сделал такую программку, чтобы проверить, как выделяется память при объявлении сразу двумерного массива:

```
int h = 3;
int w = 5;
int mat[h][w];
for (int i = 0; i < h * w; i++) {
    mat[i / w][i % w] = i + 1;
}
int* ptr = mat[0];
for (int i = 0; i < h * w; i++) {
    int val = ptr[i];
    printf("%d ", val);
}
printf("\n");
```

Получаем красивый вывод:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

Подтверждает предположение о монолитном выделении памяти под двумерный массив.

Comment: Да, в целом согласен, но у меня конкретно заданный тип под двумерный массив, поэтому вот хотел и понял как в случае с двумерным массивом. То есть является ли это условно говоря сплошный двумерный блок в памяти.

Comment: @Ilya.K. закодил всё, сейчас дополню.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже составил небольшую проверку:

```
int main() {

    int** mat = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        mat[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
        printf("mat[%d] = %p ", i, mat[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = i * 3 + j;
            printf("mat[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int* elem = &mat[1][2];
    int **ptr = &elem;
    ptr++;
    printf("mat[1] = %p", ptr); // Абсолютно другой адресс чем у mat[1]
    ptr++;
    printf("mat[2] = %p", ptr); // Абсолютно другой адресс чем у mat[2]

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("mat[%d][%d] = %d\n",i, j, ptr[i][j]);
}
```

То есть единственный способ выделить суб-матрицу в данном случае, это вручную переписать адресса всей нужной строки, как я и писал в вопросе.

Comment: Скомпилировал, вылетает ошибка в последней строке с выводом и обращением в указателю. Вообще, этот цикл как-то не к месту, когда мы прошли несколько раз итерируем _ptr_.

Давайте посмотрим чуть выше. Выражение _&mat[1][2]_ - указатель на самый средний элемент матрицы. Переменная _elem_ хранит этот указатель. А _ptr_ хранит указатель на неё, указатель на указатель на средний элемент. Когда мы итерируем _ptr_, то он переходит на раздел памяти, который вообще не наш. Если не понятно, могу нарисовать картинку :)

Comment: Да, да, цикл вместо итераций на ptr, занести в комменты, то есть я и первый вариант и второй вариант по отдельности попробовал. Да, да, все верно.